Display final part of window title instead of beginning in Windows 10 taskbar

When I have File Explorer windows open, in the taskbar the corresponding button shows the window's title, and since the whole title usually doesn't fit in the button, only the beginning of the text is shown, with a few dots appended. For example in the attached picture the whole text would be C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium but the final part is truncated and replaced with ....
I would like it to truncate and replace with ... the beginning part and show the final part instead, for example ... les\Eclipse Adoptium, because in the folders that I usually open the final part of the title is more relevant for me.
Under Settings / Taskbar I see configuration options related to the look of the taskbar button, but none about what part of the caption must be shown.
Added: However I don't want to uncheck the option "Display the full path in the title bar", I would like the full path in the title bar when the window is open, and just the truncation in the taskbar button's text to happen at the beginning instead of at the end of the button's text.
That's probably just not possible, I'm just trying to make sure.

Windows taskbar will show whatever the titlebar is. I believe you can change explorer to only show the name of the folder, not the full path, that would fix your problem.

@LPChip Thanks for the edit. I would like that when the window is open I see the whole path in the title bar, like I do now. I'm looking for a solution that only affects the button in the taskbar.

Unless there is a specific tool that emulates the taskbar, there's no solution. So any solution offered here will be workarounds, like my comment.

Each application determines what is displayed in the Taskbar. For example, in the screenshot below, Thunderbird shows it is open to Local Folders... and it also displays the submenu items Write new message and Open address book.

(Windows OS also adds the three submenu items with the darker background.)
So, if you want Windows Explorer to display only the current folder, and not the full path, as shown below:


Press WindowsE to open Explorer.
Click on the View tab.
Click the Options button.
Select Change folder and search options.
Deselect (remove check-mark) from Display the full path in the title bar.

Now, the caption to the taskbar icon for Explorer will show only the lowest-level folder selected.

Thanks, I had not thought of adding that I don't want to uncheck the option "Display the full path in the title bar", I still would like the full path in the title bar when the window is open. I added that now. I'm starting to realize that maybe it's just not possible.

What you describe is not feasible with Windows Explorer, but a third-party substitute might work, e.g., Double Commander or alternative file manager: https://alternativeto.net/software/double-commander/ . You'd need to research the specs for each, and try it.

Thank you for the pointers, I will consider those alternatives. And thanks for highlighting that whether this is possible or not doesn't depend on Windows but on the particular application that gets minimized to the taskbar. I can't +1 because of not enough reputation.
